# Integrate Bootstrap in existing web application

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, mapping, richfaces

I was assigned the task to redesign our User Interface which consists of Html based on the JSF 2.1 / Richfaces 4.2 Framework and CSS (written in Sass). The JSF is managed by Java Beans in the backend. The task also includes the integration of responsive design.

As for responsive design, I've decided to go with bootstrap 3.3.7 - if you know a better Approach please let me know!

I've succesfully integrated Bootstrap in my project and can access the styling-classes within my JSF files. So the CSS works fine, the problem comes with JavaScript (at least this is what I think)-> e.g. Dropdowns are not opening/collapsing, I've already read in multiple posts that this has to do with the JQuery conflict between Bootstrap and Richfaces' JQuery - but loading Richfaces' JQuery first didn't solve the Problem for me.

**menu.xhtml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>
 <f:facet name="first">
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="js/bootstrap.js"></h:outputScript>
 </f:facet>
</h:head>

   <div class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Anmeldung<span class="caret"> </span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><h:commandLink href="#">Action</h:commandLink></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

I have now tried to create a **static-resource-mappings.properties** file with one mapping so that all requests for jquery.js are served as requests for jquery-alternative-version.js:

```
jquery.js=resources/jquery-alternative-version.js
```

my **web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceMapping.enabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceMapping.mappingFile</param-name>
    <param-value>META-INF/richfaces/static-resource-mappings.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However this still doesn't make the Dropdown (and therefore Javascript) work for me. Am I missing something?

Note: bootstrap.css and richfaces' jquery.js appear in chromes developer tool -> Sources

Comment: Bootstrap should throw an error if there is a problem with jQuery (which there should be since RF 4.2 uses an older version). The error tells you something related to bootstrap is not getting loaded, you need to find what it is. What your pages look like is not really relevant in this case.

Comment: thanks for your help! I've updated my question as I thought it wasn't specific enough.

Comment: I feel like you're trying to a fix a problem you don't have (yet). Is bootstrap.js loaded? Any errors in the console?

Comment: bootstrap.js isn't loaded and no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved all my problems by placing my Bootstrap references at the very bottom.

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="bootstrap" name="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<h:outputScript library="bootstrap" name="js/bootstrap.js"></h:outputScript>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Richfaces' JQuery was somehow loaded at the end of the file. Hope this helps others as well!